# where is CLHLock in Java API

Tags: java, multithreading

I can not find the class CLHLock class in java api library
http://www.programering.com/a/MjM5gTNwATE.html

Comment: Why did you expect to find it in the java api library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> where is CLHLock in Java API

It is not part of the Java SE class library.  Or any of the more commonly user 3rd-party utility libraries either, as far as I can make out.

Google did find classes called `CLHLock` in a couple of GitHub projects ... but nothing that I would recommend that you add as a dependency.